# Generar Reportes en JAVA

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Estoy conectándome a mi Base de Datos que esta en **MYSQL**, uso **jdbc** en **Eclipse** para poder realizar las consulta, este código guarda en una matriz bidimensional cualquier tipo de consulta.
La matriz se crea de acuerdo a los renglones y columnas de la consulta dada.
Entonces una vez que se ah realizado la consulta y se guarda en la matriz, limpio esa matriz para poder mostrarla en un **JTable**.
Y quiero saber como poder generar un reporte de esta matriz y pasarla a un documento **PDF** o **HTML**.

```
public class oruebaDef {

    private static String sURL = "jdbc:mysql://url:port/bd?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    private static Connection con = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException {

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(sURL, "user", "password");
        String consulta = "select * from empleados;";
        String resultadoSQL = consulta;


        try {
            // Impresion del HTML
            archivo = new FileOutputStream("matriz.html");
            // archivo= new FileOutputStream("archivo.txt");
            p = new PrintStream(archivo);

            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(resultadoSQL);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            int numColumnas = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int aux;
            System.out.println("Numero de columnas " + numColumnas);

            int count = 0;

            int cantFilas = 0;
            if (rs.last()) {// Nos posicionamos al final
                cantFilas = rs.getRow();// sacamos la cantidad de filas/registros
                rs.beforeFirst();// nos posicionamos antes del inicio (como viene por defecto)
            }
            String[] datosTablaColumna = new String[cantFilas];

            String[] encabezadoTabla = new String[numColumnas];

            for (int i = 0; i < encabezadoTabla.length; i++) {
                encabezadoTabla[i] = (rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
                // System.out.println("Encabezado: " + i + " = " + encabezadoTabla[i]);
            }

            System.out.println("Hay un total de " + cantFilas + " datos");

            String[][] matriz = new String[(cantFilas + 1)][numColumnas];

            // while (rs.next()) {
            // Meter encabezados en la matriz
            for (y = 0; y < encabezadoTabla.length; y++) {
                x = 0;
                // System.out.println("x= " + x + " y= " + y + " -" + (matriz[0][y] =
                // encabezadoTabla[y]));
                matriz[0][y] = encabezadoTabla[y];
                rs.next();
                for (x = 1; x <= datosTablaColumna.length; x++) {
                    // System.out.println(matriz[x + 1][y] = rs.getString(matriz[0][y]));
                    // System.out.println("x= " + x + " y= " + y + " *" + (matriz[x][y]));
                    // System.out.println("x= " + x + " y= " + y + " *" + ((matriz[x][y]) =
                    // rs.getString(matriz[0][y])));
                    matriz[x][y] = rs.getString(matriz[0][y]);
                    rs.next();
                }
                rs.beforeFirst();
            }

            // --Quitar la primer fila de la matriz[][] para la impresion limpia de la misma
            String[][] matrizNueva = new String[(cantFilas)][numColumnas];

            for (y = 0; y < encabezadoTabla.length; y++) {
                for (x = 1; x <= datosTablaColumna.length; x++) {
                    System.out.println("-x= " + x + " -y= " + y + " --> " + (matrizNueva[x - 1][y] = matriz[x][y]));
                }
            }

            // --Quitar la primer fila de la matriz[][] para la impresion limpia de la misma

            // --------Creacion del Jtable y meterlos la matriz en JTable-----------
            // Los datos:
            TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(matrizNueva, encabezadoTabla);

            // Ponerlos en el JFrame
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(tableModel)));

            frame.add(new JButton("Imprimir") {
                {
                    addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            for (Object[] row : matrizNueva) {
                                for (Object d : row) {
                                    out.print(d);
                                }
                                out.println();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }

            }, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            frame.pack();

            frame.setVisible(true);
            // -----------Creacion del Jtable y meterlos la matriz en JTable------------




            stmt.close();
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.out.println("Error en la ejecuciï¿½n:" + sqle.getErrorCode() + " " + sqle.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes pasarle un array bidimensional de java a jasper reports. Lo que tienes que pasarle es el resultado de una instrucción SELECT de base de datos. Y tienes que usar `iReport` o el `IDE de jasper` para acomodar los campos en un reporte, y generar el archivo `jrxml`. Despues ya en java haces algo como esto:

```
try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conexion=null;
            conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/cursojfreechart","","");

            JasperDesign jd=JRXmlLoader.load("F:/CursoJavaReports/JasperReports/ReporteCursoJasper.jrxml");
            String sql="select * from empleados order by idempleado desc";
            JRDesignQuery query=new JRDesignQuery();
            query.setText(sql);
            jd.setQuery(query);

            JasperReport jr=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);

            JasperPrint jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,null,conexion);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```